# Fetch all array keys including sub-array php

Tags: php

suppose my array is like

$array = array("name"=>"john", "color" => array("blue" => "aaa", "red"=>"bbb", "green"=>"ccc"));

I want following output -

[name, color/blue, color/red, color/gree]

Is there any function in PHP where I can get this output without any complex logic?

Please help me here!
Thanks!

Comment: 1. You mean [name/john, color/blue, color/red, color/gree]. 2. What is the purpose of that data structure? 3. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want the output to be actual text or as an array?

Comment: Hi @bub, actually I want two separate arrays as an output
1st one containing only keys but if any key has an array like "color" key has
then I want sub-array keys too! like [color/blue, color/red]
2nd one containing only values like [john, aaa, bbb, ccc]

Comment: And if my array has $array = array("test" => ["aaa", "ccc", "eee"]);
then in 1st array [test/0, test/1, test/2] and in 2nd array
[aaa, ccc, eee]

Comment: Update your question with this information, don't post it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$colors=array('red', 'blue', 'green');
$array = array("name"=>"john", "color" => $colors);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.